# An array of generic objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

```js
type Foo<T = unknown> = {
  bar: T
  bar2: (v: T) => T
}

const f1 : Foo<number> = {
  bar: 42,
  bar2: (v: number) => 5 + v
}

const f2 : Foo<string> = {
  bar: "hello",
  bar2: (v: string) => v
}

// a function that takes an array of any Foo
function process: (Foo|string)[]) {
 ...
}


process([f1, f2]) // ERROR
```

It gives this error:

```
Type 'Foo<number>' is not assignable to type 'string | Foo<unknown>'.
  Type 'Foo<number>' is not assignable to type 'Foo<unknown>'.
    Types of property 'bar2' are incompatible.
      Type '(v: number) => number' is not assignable to type '(v: unknown) => unknown'.
        Types of parameters 'v' and 'v' are incompatible.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

[typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFSgXigVwHYGttwDu2AfOlAN4BQUUARgIYBOAXFMjfcwExsAUANzbIAlOjIcAvlSoBjONgDOwKADMAjFDbwk2TAFs6EJmQzVajVlAAs3ADSdLvKILZ7DxsWjIBWKAGooASppOQVlNW4tWAREZSYAS2wAc1NKR2Y2ACIACwgAG3y4LIcLHn4hKHik5K8yYNCAekaoBjUcWWAEhShgHIYVYAZcCEVW7FamJgYQKDhVcdmdKlUOrp6IAA9gac6ANQZ8zFG%20TJcdAB9qlJEAbQBdMWoQmSotnYZ9w%20PFPluNR5AA)

It's not clear for me how to get to my objective: have a function that accepts an array of any form of `Foo` for any `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get this behavior specifically for *arrays* of `[Foo<T0>, Foo<T1>, ..., Foo<TN>]` inputs is to make your function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `T` of the type arguments for each element.  That is, `T` would be `[T0, T1, ..., TN]`.  And you'd make the input to your function a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays):

```
function extractValues<T extends any[]>(
  ar: [...{ [I in keyof T]: Foo<T[I]> | string }]
) {
}
```

Here the `ar` parameter has a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) which maps each element of the `T` tuple to a corresponding `Foo` type (or a `string` I guess, as in your example).

Let's see it in action:

```
extractValues([f1, f2, "okay"]) // okay
// function extractValues<[number, string, unknown]>
```

That works; the compiler infers that `T` is the tuple type `[number, string, unknown]`, and therefore that `ar` should be of type `[Foo<number> | string, Foo<string> | string, Foo<unknown> | string]`, which it is.  Note that `number` and `string` are inferred from the mapped type.  The third tuple element can't be inferred well and falls back to `unknown`, but that's fine because it's a `string`.

What if we pass a bad input?

```
extractValues([{ bar: 1, bar2: (v: string) => v.toUpperCase() }, f1, f2]); // error
// --------------------> ~~~~
// function extractValues<[string | number, number, string]>
```

Here `T` is inferred as `[string | number, number, string]`.  And while `f1` and `f2` are fine, the value passed in as the first element is not, since `bar2` is not of type `(v: number | string) => number | string`

So that works too; it shows that the compiler really does constrain the inputs in a way that `Array<Foo<any>>` does not.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFQHxQLxQN4CgpQBGAhgE4BcUy+RZATJQBQBulyAlJutQL664BjOADsAzsCgAzAIyV4SYQFcAtoQil0WPARIUoAFjoAaGroZQWlJavWcM6AKxQA1FGa4+gkeKnn5icVIAS2EAc00cUzJKACIACwgAG0S4GJMdeiZWKECQ0Lt0d09JRWEBYCCRKAgAD2BSYnKANWJExQhRFGq6iGEAE1EoYmEQAG0AXVRGaKhRgDoF7FmASSgQqABrCBA4SSpxuQQUUeXJqAAfHPq8qB5xzjxPWvrG4Ba2jsZRmSNfX5i4BtiCAYvcoAB6cFQQHA3CQqSlcqVYTdF7NVrtTqjaxqUi-XJhX6lDbCOAAd2Ek34zwa6I+oi+S10lGkvzMWUoBPyXDcc2AcAAqmBIKQAMLEUQQRicHi-H6+e4AbghUPUpDgpDhUJKZQqVRpr3emMQoy5FygOPUv0teKuwTCkyAA)

Comment: That's great, I learned a lot, thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the function argument to remain generic, you'll need to make the function itself generic (more info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.htm))

So it would something like this

```js
// a function that takes an array of any Foo
function extractValues<T>(ar: Foo<T>[]) {
    // ...
}

extractValues([f1]) // this will now work
```

If you'd like the array to accept mixed types of `Foo`, you can type it like this

```
function extractValues(ar: (Foo<number> | Foo<string>)[]) {
    // ...
}

extractValues([f1, f2]) // you can now pass a heterogeneous array
```

If you absolutely must, this will accept any type of foo. But using `any` beats the purpose of typescript, so it's considered a code smell

```
function extractValues(ar: Foo<any>[]) {
    // ...
}

extractValues([f1, f2]) // you can now pass a heterogeneous array
```

Comment: Ok, so it seems there are no "dynamic" way to do it, outside of the "any cheating code" solution :)

Comment: If you need heterogeneous arrays, then "any" is the only catch all you have. But I'd still encourage you to stay away from it if possible. Unless the function is supposed to handle all types, I'd say using a union type as an alternative would be better. AllFooTypes = number | string | boolean ...

Comment: It would be my choice too but I don't have control over what `T` is as any user of the lib can put what he want

Answer (score 0):

I am new to type script but this code doesn't throw any error :

```
type Foo<T = any> = {
  bar: T
  bar2: (v: T) => T
}

const f1 : Foo<any> = {
  bar: 42,
  bar2: (v: number) => 5 + v
}

const f2 : Foo<any> = {
  bar: "hello",
  bar2: (v: string) => v
}
```

with using "any" it can adjust to what inputs its obtaining(basically its a cheat type) but yeah  , hope this helps !